# Using bootstrap related tags inside JSF2 h:inputText component

Tags: jsf-2, twitter-bootstrap

Is there anyway to use bootstrap related tags in JSF2 components? For example I'm interested in using the bootstrap typeahead feature which requires something like

```
<h:inputText id="typeahead" type="text" data-provide="typeahead"></h:inputText>
```

but since `data-provide` doesn't exist for `h:inputText` it gets stripped out and so the typeahead feature would obviously not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on JSF version you're using.

In **JSF 2.0/2.1**, it's not possible to specify additional attributes. The JSF HTML renderers will only render predefined attributes. You'd need to create a custom renderer to achieve the desired job. To minimize boilerplate code, you're forced to extend the implementation-specific renderer. It's unclear which one you're using, so here's just a Mojarra targeted example:

```
import com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TextRenderer;

public class MyTextRenderer extends TextRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void getEndTextToRender(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String currentValue) throws IOException {
        Object dataProvide = component.getAttributes().get("data-provide");

        if (dataProvide != null) {
            context.getResponseWriter().writeAttribute("data-provide", dataProvide, null);
        }

        super.getEndTextToRender(context, component, currentValue);
    }

}
```

Register it as follows in `faces-config.xml` to get it to run:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Input</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Text</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.MyTextRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

---

In **JSF 2.2**, it's possible by the new `passthrough` namespace or the `<f:passThroughAttribute>` tag. See also [What's new in JSF 2.2? - HTML5 Pass-through attributes](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#1089).

Thus, so:

```
<html ... xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
...
<h:inputText id="typeahead" a:data-provide="typeahead" />
```

*(note that the `type` attribute defaults to `text` already)*

Or:

```
<h:inputText id="typeahead">
    <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-provide" value="typeahead" />
</h:inputText>
```

#### See also:

- [Custom HTML tag attributes are not rendered by JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666472/custom-html-tag-attributes-are-not-rendered-by-jsf/)

Comment: i am using mojarra 2.2.4 but it doesn't have `<f:passThroughAttribute />`. is the problem from my mojarra library or it need more config.  thanks.